# Get All Shipping Classes in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I've been unable to crack this nut, but can't help feel that I'm missing something simple.

I'm developing a WooCommerce plugin that should provide a list of shipping classes on its admin settings page. The following code as suggested in another question's answer indicated that the following should work:

```
$shipping           = new \WC_Shipping();
$shipping_classes   = $shipping->get_shipping_classes();
var_dump($shipping_classes);
die();
```

Unfortunately the output is an empty array.

I am using Wordpress 4.9.5 and WooCommerce 3.3.5. Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**
I have the exact same problem as outlined here:
[get_terms() returns Invalid Taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777661/get-terms-returns-invalid-taxonomy/49838326#49838326) and have provided a work-around. However, I do not feel that is a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to get all of the shipping classes, or the shipping methods? Also, have you tried removing the slash in front of `WC_Shipping();`?

Answer (score 6):

To get all the shipping classes you just need the following:

```
$shipping_classes = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_shipping_class', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
```

Tested and works. This will give you an array of the `WP_Term` objects of all shipping classes.

> In Woocommerce the shipping classes are under `product_shipping_class` custom taxonomy.

---

Or you can use this custom function with a simple SQL query:

```
function wc_get_shipping_classes(){
    global $wpdb;
    $return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_shipping_class'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

USAGE (test example):

```
$shipping_classes = wc_get_shipping_classes(); // Get Shipping Classes
echo '<pre>'; print_r($shipping_classes); echo '</pre>'; // Test raw output
```

Comment: This does not actually work in my case. I have tried this, and it only returns a single shipping class for some reason, not all of them. I added a link in the original question to another question I found that more precisely poses the exact issue. I also provided a work-around there, but I do not think that was a proper solution.

Comment: @mike.bronner Very, strange because all shipping classes are terms from "product_shipping_class" custom taxonomy in Woocommerce. So **I have updated my answer, adding a 2nd way**… Try it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort. :) I'm happy looping through the results of `get_terms()` (without any arguments) and filtering out my results. I'm fairly confident there is a bug or conflict somewhere that is wreaking havok. :|

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy...

```php
/** 
 * @var WP_Terms[] $shipping_classes
 */
$shipping_classes = WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_classes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is still looking for a solution :)

```
$WC_Shipping = new WC_Shipping();
$shipping_classes = $WC_Shipping->get_shipping_classes();
var_dump($shipping_classes);
```